# Swift 3: private required initializer possible?

Tags: swift

Consider following code:

```
private class MyClass {
    private required init(_ i: Int) {
    }
}
```

Now, I'm getting compiler error:
`'required' initializer must be as accessible as its enclosing type`. But the type is declared as `private`.

I thought the issue might be that the class is declared on a file level, so it's 
`private` type

> restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration.

as [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html). So it effectively makes it `fileprivate`, since the enclosing declaration is a file. But I'm getting the same error even for nested private classes.

When I declare initializer as `fileprivate` it works:

```
private class MyClass {
    private class MyNested {
        fileprivate required init(_ i: Int) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: why `private` is not correct here? Is it possible to declare `private required` initializer?

I ask because I want to understand the error in the first place.

Why I need it is rather different question, but initially I wrote such code:

```
private class MyClass {
    private class MyNested {
        private init(_ i: Int) {
        }
        func foo() {
            var f = type(of: self).init(1)
        }
    }
}
```

and then had to add `required` declaration specifier as I was getting the error: `constructing an object of class type 'MyClass.MyNested' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer`

**Answer:**
Thanks to @SørenMortensen:

> The issue with the private initialiser is that the `MyNested` class is accessible within `MyClass`, but the initialiser is only accessible within `MyNested`, and therefore is not as accessible as its enclosing type. And as @Hamish points out, the concept of a `required` initialiser is mutually exclusive with the concept of a `private` initialiser.

So it looks like it is not possible to have `private required` initializer, indeed. And in my case I can make `MyNested` class to be `final` and then make the initializer `private` not making it `required`.

Comment: What purpose would a `private required` initialiser serve? No subclasses could ever possibly see (and therefore implement) it, as `private` limits its visibility to the declaration of `MyClass`.

Comment: You're correct about the first point, which is that the declaration `private class MyClass` makes the class `fileprivate`, because it's declared at the top level of the file. The issue with the `private` initialiser is that the `MyNested` class is accessible within `MyClass`, but the initialiser is only accessible within `MyNested`, and therefore is not as accessible as its enclosing type. And as @Hamish points out, the concept of a `required` initialiser is mutually exclusive with the concept of a private initialiser.

Comment: @Hamish @SørenMortensen Thanks. I think I see it now. So it looks like it is not possible to have `private required` initializer, indeed. And in my case I can make `MyNested` class to be `final` and then make the initializer `private` not making it `required`.

Comment: @Andrey Quite correct :)

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want one?

The purpose of `required` means that one is forced to use this initialization when declaring this class. Like @Hamish said, setting it as `private` would just result in classes unable to see it and cannot declare it. If you want additional setup but don't want it to be accessible, why not just call a `private func` within a `required init`?